# Jackrabbit + Spring JTA transactions not working

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, jackrabbit

I'm trying to configure Jackrabbit with Spring to use transactions. For what I've researched already, I need JCA classes to manage the remote repository, so, I'm using Jencks which is the most recommended implementation for doing this.

However, when testing, I can't make the transactions to work.

This is my configuration file:

```
<!-- JCA Transaction Manager Implementation -->
<bean id="txManagerJencks" class="org.jencks.factory.TransactionManagerFactoryBean" />

<!-- JCA Connection Manager Implementation -->
<bean id="pooledConnectionManagerJcr" class="org.jencks.factory.ConnectionManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManagerJencks" />
    <property name="transaction" value="xa" />
    <property name="poolMinSize" value="${jcr.transactions.pool.min.size}"/>
    <property name="poolMaxSize" value="${jcr.transactions.pool.max.size}"/>
    <property name="connectionMaxIdleMinutes" value="${jcr.transactions.connection.max.idle.minutes}" />      
</bean>

<!-- JCA Managed Repository -->
<bean id="repositoryManagedConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" destroy-method="finalize">
    <property name="repositoryURI" value="${jcr.server.rmi.url}" />
    <property name="bindSessionToTransaction" value="true" />
    <property name="startRepositoryImmediately" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- Repository Configuration -->
<bean id="jcrRepository" class="org.springframework.jca.support.LocalConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="managedConnectionFactory" ref="repositoryManagedConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="connectionManager" ref="pooledConnectionManagerJcr"/>
</bean>

<!-- JCR Credentials -->
<bean id="jcrCredentials" class="javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${jcr.user}"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean factory-bean="jcrCredentialsPassword" factory-method="toCharArray"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="jcrCredentialsPassword" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${jcr.user}"/>
</bean>

<!-- JCR Session Factory -->
<bean id="jcrSessionFactory" class="org.springmodules.jcr.JcrSessionFactory">
    <property name="repository" ref="jcrRepository"/>
    <property name="credentials" ref="jcrCredentials"/>
    <property name="workspaceName" value="${jcr.workspace}"/>

    <property name="sessionHolderProviderManager">
        <bean class="com.jetsonsys.jcr.support.SingleRepositorySessionHolderProviderManager">
            <property name="sessionProvider">
                    <bean class="org.springmodules.jcr.jackrabbit.support.JackRabbitSessionHolderProvider"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>



<!-- Edit: This fixed the problem -->

<!-- JTA transactional advice (what 'happens') -->
<tx:advice id="txAdviceJCA" transaction-manager="txManagerJencks">
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- All methods starting with 'get', 'has' and 'validate' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="test*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- Other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- AOP. Ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of an operation defined in the com.jetsonsys.plm.cms package -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="plmRepositoryServiceOperation" expression="execution(* com.jetsonsys.plm.cms.*RepositoryService.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceJCA" pointcut-ref="plmRepositoryServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

The RepositoryDAO looks like this to get the sessions:

```
@Autowired
private JcrSessionFactory jcrSessionFactory;

/**
 * Initializes the session for all the class methods.
 */
Session getSession() throws DAOException {

    try {

        Session session = jcrSessionFactory.getSession();

        return session;

    } catch (RepositoryException ex) {
        log.error("Error creating JCR Session. [{}]", ex.getMessage());
        throw new DAOException(ex.getMessage(), ErrorCode.REPOSITORY_SESSION);
    } 
}
```

The RepositoryService that attemps to delete a Node and then throws an exception to rollback:

```
/**
 * Deletes a Deal from the Repository.
 * 
 * @param dealId
 * @throws PLMException 
 */
public void deleteDeal(String dealId) throws PLMException {

    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Deleting deal from repository [dealId = {}]", dealId);
    }

    Session session = null;

    try {

        session = repositoryDAO.getSession();

        Node dealsNode = getDealsNode(session);

        String dealNodeName = RepositoryConstants.DEAL_NODE_PREFIX + dealId;

        repositoryDAO.deleteFolder(dealsNode, dealNodeName);

        session.save();

        throw new Exception("TESTTTTT");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error deleting the Deal {}. {}", dealId, ex.getMessage());
        throw new ServiceException(String.format("Error deleting the  Deal %s. %s", dealId, ex.getMessage()), ErrorCode.REPOSITORY_DELETE);
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.logout();
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result here is the exception is thrown and the Node is kept in the repository, however the Node always get deleted.

I'm trying to find configuration examples for Jackrabbit TX with Spring, but the ones I've found uses very old versions of the libraries.

I'm using: 
Spring 4.1.6 
Jackrabbit 2.10 
Jencks 2.2

Thanks in advance for your help. 
-Alejandro

************************************* 
* EDIT                              * 
*************************************

Got it to work! Just add the a Transactional Advice for the Jencks Transaction and then an Aspect to make it execute by all the classes I need.

Comment: I'm amazed this works, given the stone-aged springmodules (last updated: 14-Mar-2007). Isn't there a more modern way nowadays?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've researched a lot and this was all got. If someone knows a better way, please, let us know.